# Functionality of Numpy's nanmax in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have an array `X` of size `[?, n]` (the first dimension is the batch size).
I would like to get the `k` biggest numbers (for each vector in the batch), where some of them are `nan`. In usual numpy I would use the function `nanmax`, but it doesn't seem to be present in Tensorflow.

I tried using `nn.top_k` with the full vector (with `nans`) but it doesn't seem to work properly - it gives back a vector that has some `nan` values even though there are enough numbers to fill the `k` it gets at input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all your `nan` values with negative infinities and use `top_k`

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
c = a/b
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print sess.run(tf.nn.top_k(c)[0])
infinities = tf.constant(-np.inf, shape=(4,))
c_fixed = tf.select(tf.is_nan(c), infinities, c)
print sess.run(tf.nn.top_k(c_fixed)[0])
```

This gives

```
[ nan]
[ 1.]
```